# problem with returning from function in c++/c

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function

i have this problem with returning from function.
it's a search function, it should return 1 if the function find the value that i give but No, it's returning the 0 instead of 1. (sorry for my bad english.)

```
int rech(int tab[],int n,int i,int r){
    if(i<n){
        if(tab[i]==r){
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
        rech(tab,n,i,r);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int tab[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d",rech(tab,5,0,2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You are not using the return value of `rech`. `0` is always returned. Try `return rech(...)`

Comment: @JVApen C++ is mostly a superset of C, and most C features like `printf` work just fine. Don't judge.

Comment: why make this recursive?

Comment: @MarkRansom The general consensus here is to pick one language.

Comment: I don't judge you wanting to use it in C++, I do if you are learning it: [https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk](Stop teaching C - Kate Gregory)

Comment: Thinking of C++ as a  super set of C gives a lot of people a lot of grief.  It's better to think of them as two completely separate languages when first starting out.

Comment: @Broman then that should have been the comment. The one I was responding to said only "Why do you believe you are writing C++?" before it was edited, which is a bit hostile for a new contributor.

Comment: @MarkRansom Maybe I'm insensitive then, cause I cannot see how that could be hostile. I think it's a very polite suggestion.

Comment: @Broman there was no suggestion; that was edited in after I made my comment. The question itself is a bit accusatory. The code would compile and run in any compliant C++ compiler.

Comment: @Mark I miss clicked indeed, second sentence came later though should have been in the original post.

Comment: @MarkRansom In that case I see it as just a perfectly valid and motivated question. Even though this particular code is both valid C++ and C you should say which language you intend to use. And judging strictly from the style of code, C is definitely the best guess. This code is also valid Objective C. Should that tag also be used?

Comment: hey, thank you guys for the help this is the first question from me on this site i believe that i am writing in c++ cause i know nothing from c i started with c++ instead of c  and i am just a newbie in c++ so i'll retag it if you want it , *just as @MarkRansom said  the code run  perfectly on c++ ,shloud i run it on c instead*

Comment: If it is your intention to write C++ code go ahead and tag the question that way. Just be aware that you're going to get some *helpful* comments about better ways of doing things in C++.

Comment: actually i want to write code with c++ not with c , thank you @MarkRansom for the advice

Comment: @minn If you want to code C++, well I'd say you're doing it wrong. Read a C++ tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through it together.

When rech gets called the first time:

First time we call rech:
`rech(tab = {1,2,3,4,5}, n = 5, i = 0, r = 2)`
is `i < n` or `0 < 5`? This is true.
Now we check if `tab[i] == r` or `1 == 2`. This is false.
We increase i and start over again

Second time we call rech:
`rech(tab = {1,2,3,4,5}, n = 5, i = 1, r = 2)`
is `tab[i] < r` or `1 < 5`? This is true.
Now we check if `tab[i] == r` or `2 == 2`. This is true.
We return 1 back to the first time rech got called.

Back to the first time we call rech:
`rech(tab, n, i, r)` returned 1. So, in coding terms this would
look like `1;` which does nothing.

Now we are done with the if statement and return 0 to main.

main now prints out a 0 and the program ends.

This is the process of debugging the code.

To have the program return the 1 back to main instead you'll want to have it return the rech function because otherwise, the recursive call does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `return` you will return to the caller, which in a recursive function will mean the same function most of the times.

Change

```
rech(tab,n,i,r);
```

to

```
return rech(tab,n,i,r);
```

Comment: @minn Pick cwbusacker's answer as accepted instead of mine. It's a better answer and he need the reputation better than me. :)

Comment: okay  i change it to cwbusacker's answer and thank you for the help again ;)

Comment: Hey @Broman Thanks for the help! I can now comment to thank you for sacrificing your reputation for mine!

Comment: @cwbusacker No worries, and after all, your answer was better.